# Can't connect to Postgresql 13 server using Npgsql, destination computer actively deny connection

Tags: c#, wpf, npgsql

In my app, when i click button

```
<Button x:Name="SQLconnectionButtonTest" Content="Test SQL connection" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="SQLconnectionButtonTest_Click"></Button>
```

and a code:

```
public void SQLconnectionButtonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    var cs = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=postgres123;Database=testdb";
    using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT version()";
    using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
    var version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    MessageBox.Show($"Postgres version: {version}");
}
```

I have an error:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
In english would be "can not establish the connection, because the destination computer actively refusing it.
Postgresql server is running, i have created database testdb in pgadmin

Comment: And you can connect some other query tool to it just fine, using the same connection string?

Comment: i have only this

Comment: Ok, so how about installing and trying something else ? Also have a read of https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/ and check your pg is allowing localhost connections.

Comment: i have read this, i have uninstalled postgresql 13 and installed 9.6. To both of them, i can connect from command line using psql -h localhost -p 5435 -U postgres. Or, from second computer psql -h 192.168.0.120 -p 5435 -U postgres. But still i cant connect from app

Comment: Those command lines specify the port as 5435, but the default port is 5432. The connection string you posted doesn't specify `Port=5435`

Comment: i have tried it on postgresql 13 and it did not help. But i have today tried it on postgresql 9.6 and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems that perhaps your PG was running on a non standard port and the required port number specification was missing from the connection string. You noted that there was a difference in behavior between PG 13 and PG9.6; to that end I'd say to use something like TCPView to verify what port and interface PG is listening on, and ensure the connection string details match. Also check whether your windows firewall is operating in mode where the application that is running is a factor in whether the connection is permitted or not, rather than just the port